# Problems with positioning and resizing

Tags: css, html

I'm having trouble with the layout of one of my pages (http://jsfiddle.net/NeonGuilmon/pghtZ/5/)

I'm trying to create the interface of a chatroom, with the section `room` in the top-left of the screen, (100% - 200px) in width and height, section `users` in the top-left, 50% height and 200px width, section `friends` in the bottom left with the same dimensions ad `users`, and `chat-bar` in the bottom right, 200px in height and (100% - 200px) in width.

As you can see from my fiddle, I messed up pretty badly, and I have no idea where to go next. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your `room` is not 100% - 200px it is more 100% + 200px (margin-right:200px).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem: I didn't realize CSS `calc` was so widely supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend reading the following two links:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Correctly understanding how position/display work and the difference between margin/ etc is key.

You are currently working with display:block. This basically means that each  element will be placed under the next one.

You are using right-margin. This will force a white margin on the right of the element and will not allow anything to sit in that space

Finally if you want to align 4 block elements side by side using a table can ease a lot of the problem (don't go overboard with tables though).

So the easiest way to set something like this up: (I placed the layout on the html but you can put it in the css. Also remove all the positioning and height hints you currently have on your sections. they should just take all the space they can inside the table cell

```
<table height="100%" border=1> 
  <tr height=50%>
    <td width=100%><section id="room">room</section></td>
    <td width=200px><section id="users">users</section></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr height=50%>
    <td><section id="friends">friends</section></td>
    <td><section id="chat-bar">chatbar</section></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```